# Trying to use Git to push the master branch up to Heroku and receiving error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sqlite

I tried to use Git to push the master branch up to Heroku; my input was: $ git push heroku master. In my Command line output, it reads - "remote: An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot remote:        continue. remote: Make sure that `gem install sqlite3"

May I proceed or should I correct? Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming specific question. The best place for this would be ServerFault.

Comment: @Fallso No! It belongs to here. Just need to provide more info.

Comment: @Pavan I thought SO was only for programming related questions? I quick survey of the question made it looks as if this was a software configuration issue outside of git.

Comment: @Fallso Its not a software configuration issue outside of git

Comment: @Pavan OK, I stand corrected! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your project ready for Heroku, you need to have the appropriate Heroku gems installed, in your Gemfile add:

```
group: :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Make sure you install the gems with `$ bundle`, then add all the changes and commit them. Then run `$ git push heroku master`

Heroku doesn't support SQLite3. You should use the pg gem for production. Also, you need rails_12factor to support static asset serving and logging. I recommend checking out the Heroku page for more information:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Comment: I appreciate your assistance; it helped. Thanks for the link, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using PosgreSQL for Heroku.

Add the following to your gemfile (for all environments though you can just add it to run in production if you don't have PostgreSQL installed locally yet):

```
gem 'pg'
```

Commit it to Github and push it to Heroku.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Replace sqlite3 with pg"
git push heroku master
```

If you're interested in setting up a really awesome RoR development environment that includes PostgreSQL, I'd recommend checking out https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Your assistance was spot-on! And I appreciate the PostgreSQL link.